# Starting freelance career as a programmer

Tags: web-development, programmer

It's my second semester of college and I've taken some relatively advanced data structures classes and java programming. I have written a solid amount of programs in a variety of different languages over the past few years. I'd like to get a start as a freelance programmer/web developer. Where should I start?

Comment: Start by searching this site for the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make your bones at all the freelancer sites and do the dirty work until you have a reputation then you will likely find some regular clients that you can make some decent money with. Any Angular experience?

Comment: Hi Entre, I have the same query, and having angular experience. Any advice/suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: Build something and put it on your website. If you don't have your own website, up to date, and  displaying either the work for other clients or your own projects, you are not going anywhere.

Comment: I got my start (it was a long time ago) putting up signs on campus for tutoring and talking to professors about their needs. Lots of professors need people to write scripts, programs, etc. to crunch their research data.

Answer (score 1):

I was writing recently on the topic: [The ultimate guide to land a freelance gig – End to End](http://blog.envoice.in/ultimate-guide-land-freelance-gig-end-end/)

To start with you will need to:

1. Polish your freelancing portfolio
2. Learn more about the client you are going to pitch to
3. Learn more about the client you are going to pitch to
4. Prepare for the first meeting
5. Learn how to create an estimate

Answer (score 1):

There are many Freelancing websites available on the Internet. I would not suggest where to start, but I can help with *how* to start it.

1. Portfolio is very important. Usually clients don't go with a fresher who freelances. To gain their trust we need to showcase our accomplishments. For example, you can post your photos or videos of your website designed, or a user simplified e-commerce website in low effort and budget etc.
2. If you get your first client, then gather his actual requirements and satisfy him with your quality deliverables. His feedback is very important to grasp other clients.
3. Always be in touch with your old clients. Because in software industry, all websites and software keep on updating with new features. So for sure he will have plenty of ideas to implement for the future. So grab all those opportunities.
4. Client will approach new freelancers only for cost-cutting. So you can't charge them much in early stages. Once your gain confidence, then you can demand more for it.

I would suggest to kick start with freelancer.com and upwork.com.